# Asus Zephyrus G15 2021 with MT7921 WiFi Card: very slow internet via WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless, google-chrome, dns, asus

Speedtest results show good results, as it is supposed to be

```
user@laptop:~$ speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from <redacted>...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by <redacted>: 10.242 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 95.78 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 116.80 Mbit/s
```

However, upon normal internet browsing via Google Chrome, it takes too long to load the webpage. I suspected it to be a DNS issue. I updated the DNS to Google DNS configuration for both IPv4 and IPv6. But the issue is still there.

My WiFi card is `Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter`, as listed by `lspci`.

Comment: What does `ip link` say your MTU is? It should be 1492 for WiFi, not 1500.

Comment: It says 1500, but why should it be 1492?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Download rate from nas is (almost) half in Ubuntu than Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383390/why-download-rate-from-nas-is-almost-half-in-ubuntu-than-windows)